# grep output is not in stdout or stderr

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, stdout

I'm trying to find files that contain 'ash' and 'bun' with the following bash command:

```
grep --line-buffered -ril ash  | xargs -d '\n' grep -il bun
```

Output from the first grep only (the names of files containing 'ash') appears as expected on the terminal screen, but nothing is being printed to the pipe.  I verified this with:

```
grep --line-buffered -ril ash &> junk
```

junk is empty.

I have GNOME Terminal 3.6.2, GNU grep 2.16 and Ubuntu 14.04.  The output from grep is coloured.

I'm aware of grep's buffering quirks but the output appears on separate lines, so I assume it's being flushed.

Anybody?

Comment: Have you tried the simpler version `grep -ril foo | xarg grep -il bar`? Works for me. There is also [this simpler syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529717/6378557).

Comment: Thanks xenoid, some helpful ideas there (I'm not exactly sure what \`cat -\` is doing, but it looks promising).  I've discovered that my issue remains a buffering issue.  I thought --line-buffered would flush output to the pipe, but it doesn't seem to.   The command works, it just doesn't print anything to the pipe until it's finished processing (even though the output is visible on the terminal).

Comment: You should also (and maybe, only ) force line-buffering on the second instance...

Comment: For some reason it's working more quickly now.  Must be a system issue.  --line-buffered on first, second or both doesn't seem to make any difference..